# echoing a result from the database with php only returns 1 result

Tags: php

I'm trying to get results from a database and return the data to my page.

I have 2 files, findtask, and functions.
In functions I have some code that grabs all my data from the table.
I then used a while loop to grab the stuff if I echo the results from the functions script it returns as it should id 1 2 and 3, my issue starts when trying to get the result from findtask script that only gets last result.

```
<?php
public function ShowOpenTasks ()
{
//i leave usersemail blank, because i only want tasks to show on this page if there not assigned.
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `usersemail` = ''";
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query)) {
        exit(mysqli_error($this->db));
    }
    $data = [];
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data = $row;
            echo $data['id'];
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
?>
```

My findtask page is

```
require __DIR__ . '/lib/functions.php';
$app = new FunctionClass();
$task = $app->ShowOpenTasks();
echo $task['id'] //id being the name of the id table of the task.
```

This one will only turn the last id for some reason.

What is wrong and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Your while loop overwrites $data in each loop thats why you only get the last result. You could just return the result array and echo out in a loop in your view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will only return last id since you are setting data to equal row

```
$data = $row;
```

So each row you replace it with the last one.

I guess you want an array instead, so you could do:

```
$data[] = $row;
```

then to print out all tasks:

```
$task = $app->ShowOpenTasks();
print_r($task);
```

This would give you an array of results.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problame and now results in
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [usersemail] => [taskname] => test [details] => nothing ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [usersemail] => [taskname] => randomtest [details] => another test again to see stuff ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [usersemail] => [taskname] => bug [details] => only showing one result ? ) )

Comment: Hmm, how would i be able to get for example just the id out of that? i tried $task[id] in findtask however this did not result in what i expected.

Comment: $task[0]['id'] for first row results.

Comment: that works, but not what i really had in mind, that will of course only return the first id i would need something that returns all the id's just like $task dose. for example the array i posted above of the results, i need to be able to show the id's or just the taskname  etc

Comment: Well $data is an array; you can loop through it with for example foreach.